# Checkout as guest with shopware 6 store-api

Tags: shopware6

I am using the shopware 6 `store-api` and attempting to convert a cart to an order as a guest. Beforehand, I register the guest using the `account/register` endpoint with the `guest: true` parameter.

However, when I try to convert the cart to an order with `checkout/order`, I receive the error `CHECKOUT__CUSTOMER_NOT_LOGGED_IN`. I understand that this is because I am a guest, but I cannot login because this requires a password. Is there a way to fix this issue and convert the cart to an order as a guest?

Comment: without more details @newgennerd's answer is the best. The error you mention is thrown if the context lacks the customer object. Which would mean that you are not re-using the context-token generated in the register call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As response from the register-api-call you get a new `sw-context-token` returned as a header.
You need to use this token from there on for all following api-requests, as it contains all customer related context.